# Can't generate jasper report on spring

Tags: spring-boot, nullpointerexception, jasper-reports

I am trying to generate a PDF file using JasperReports, however, regardless of how I try it, it's giving me a NullPointerException.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/520803/getting-null-pointer-exception-fillreport

Tried looking there, and changed the jasper properties file, but it didn't do anything and i'm still getting the same error.

Tried absolute paths, relative paths, getting resource as stream, nothing

This is the code i'm using to generate the report

```
public String generateInvoiceFor (Reservation reservation) throws JRException {

        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("I:\\anoranzaHopefullyFinal\\src\\main\\resources\\jasper\\FacturaFinalFinal.jrxml");

        List<Reservation> reservations = reservationService.getAll();

        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jrBeanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(reservations);

        Map<String,Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();

        parameters.put("Idparam", reservation.getId());

        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, jrBeanCollectionDataSource);

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "jasper/jasperOutput/Factura.pdf");

        return "Report successfully generated @path= jasper/jasperOutput/";



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your datasource and jasperPrint. If there is no problem try this.

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
exporter.setExporterOutput(
  new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("PDF NAME IS HERE.pdf"));

SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig
  = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);

SimplePdfExporterConfiguration exportConfig
   = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
exportConfig.setMetadataAuthor("Auth name is here");
exportConfig.setEncrypted(true);
exportConfig.setAllowedPermissionsHint("PRINTING");

exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);
exporter.setConfiguration(exportConfig);

exporter.exportReport();
```